# Problemas con setw(x)

Tags: c++

Por algún motivo setw(numero) no deja espacios. Tengo la biblioteca correspondiente y creo que la nomenclatura es la correcta.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int const TAM_CODIGO=4;

typedef enum{ROJO,AZUL,VERDE,AMARILLO,MARRON,BLANCO} tColor;
typedef tColor tCodigo[TAM_CODIGO];

void menu();
void textoMenu();
void codigoHumano(tCodigo hipotesis);
void codigoAleatorio(tCodigo codigo, bool admiteRepetidos);
char colorMaquina(tColor a);
void compararCodigos(const tCodigo codigo, const tCodigo hipotesis, int& colocados, int& descolocados);


int main()
{
    cout << setw(6) << "[Este programa no usa tildes por motivos tecnicos]" << endl << endl;
    cout << setw(6) << "Mastermind" << endl << setw(6) << "==========" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Descubre el codigo secreto! En cada partida, pensare un codigo de colores que tendras que adivinar. ";
    cout << "En cada intento que hagas te dare pistas, diciendote cuantos colores de los que has dicho estan bien colocados, y cuantos no.";
    cout << endl<< endl << "Averigua el codigo secreto en el menor numero posible de intentos!" << endl <<endl;
    menu();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que la cantidad de letras que tiene el texto es mayor a la alineación, si colocas por ejemplo 55 notarás se mueve. Para decirlo de forma sencilla, el setw se mueve tantos espacios a la derecha como lo indiques y luego escribe el texto a la izquierda, por eso si el texto es mayor a la cantidad del setw, se irá desplazando cuando llene los espacios del setw.